How to distinguish what should be put into infrastructure in clean architecture or hexagonal architecture？
If I use clean architecture or hexagonal architecture in my application, for the frameworks I use in my project, such as spring, springmvc, spring-ai, etc. I think spring and springmvc are inseparable from the business code as a whole, but spring-ai is likely to be replaced by langchain, etc. so it needs to be treated as an infrastructure?
I'm wondering if there are any principles for distinguishing what goes into the infrastructure and what is integrated with the business code.

What are the input and output adapters included in clean architecture or hexagonal architecture ? For example, spring-ai framework is strongly related to the business code, but he will request the external big model, this kind of belongs to the output adapter?
